# Angular bootstrap lightbox Unknown provider error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I included all the necessary files and added the 'bootstrapLightbox' as a dependency to my module, but i keep getting this error when I'm adding the 'Lightbox' parameter to my controller:

Unknown provider: $uibModalProvider <- $uibModal <- Lightbox <- Lightbox

I will appreciate any help on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Bootstrap modal's version was out of date.

Comment: Can you please explain.I am also getting same error.I am using this ui-bootstrap.<script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.0.min.js"></script>